# @bot.command() doesn't run - No errors show up

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'))
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm trying to get my bot to respond "hi" when a user runs command "!hi". The problem is that the command doesn't run and no errors show up as well. The code within the .py file is exactly as it is shown (except TOKEN is replaced with an actual Token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `client`, and decorating the command with `bot.command()`, you have to either use `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot` not both.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commmands.Bot(command_prefix=command.when_mentioned_or("!"), intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi")

# You can also use events with `commands.Bot`
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using both discord.Client and commands.Bot

here's how to fix it:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "Your Token"
Intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), Intents=Intents)


@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi")

client.run(TOKEN)
```